# Example on how to listen live to an audio input device

Tags: c#, naudio

I am very inexperienced with C#. I am trying to create a simple button that when clicked, will start listening live to the audio input device that is pre-selected. I have tried using the Naudio reference, but haven't been able to get anything to work yet. Could someone help me?

In simpler terms, I want to hear myself talking through the microphone and it be immediately broadcasted over the speaker. I know third party apps can do this, but this is just to get started. I am going to build on this, and create something with multiple channels and multiple inputs that will output to the same speaker